# Ipv6 Proxies run on localhost but not on Google Cloud VPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipv6, google-compute-engine, server-settings

I'm trying to pull user data from instagram public api with PHP Curl. I am using IPV6 proxy on my curl connection.

I get different results in localhost and google cloud using the same codes. When I use IPV6, I get the result as bool(false) in google cloud. But I can successfully fetch user data on localhost

**I think the problem is caused by the server settings. When I try it with IPv4, it works without any problem on the server**

I have no idea what the underlying problem is. 
Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [VPC network documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications):

> VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic. They do not support
>   broadcast, multicast, or IPv6 traffic within the network; VMs in the
>   VPC network can only send to IPv4 destinations and only receive
>   traffic from IPv4 sources. However, it is possible to create an IPv6
>   address for a [global load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6).

Please let me know if you need more details and it'll be great if you provide more details about your proxy and server configuration in that case.

Comment: Thanks bro. I don't know what to do right now because I don't know enough about the protocols. Can you give some more detailed information about what I need to do to activate IPV6?

Comment: Let's start with some details about your proxy and server configuration. Why do you need IPv6 for this requests?

Comment: I'm trying to pull data from Instagram public api. Ipv6 Cheaper than Ipv4

Comment: You can join this feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904387 and use IPv4 instead of IPv6 for a while.